# Workflow to ingest files from Zoom audio recorder

Tags: audio, workflow

I use a Zoom H5 audio recorder, and when I copy the audio files from it I like to have them sitting next to the video files they correspond too.

The problem is the way Zoom stores files: every clip in its own folder. Copying all those files into one single folder can take a long time when there are 100+ clips.

Does anyone know of any software, or workflow in Premiere/Prelude to make this easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If youre hopefully running windows, use explorer (My Computer). Navigate to the SD card. In the search box for that window, type *.wav (or whatever extension you used to record).

The window will then display all the WAV files found on the card, without the folder. Select all of them. Copy. Paste to a new folder.

If you encounter conflicts in terms of clip name, use the 3rd command called "Allow Windows to Resolve", which will create v2 v3 v4 of the files which use the same file name.

Comment: And what if you're working on a mac...? :-/